# Finding the index or unique values from a dataframe column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe

```
TableName Function Argument
A         func1    3
B         func1    4
A         func2    6
B         func2    2
C         func1    5
```

I want to first find out the unique TableName in the dataframe which is simple using unique function. However, I also need the indexes of unique mapped to the value.Something like:

```
TableName Index
A         1 3
B         2 4
C         5
```

Later I want to read this output to get the unique TableName value (e.g. A) and then use each index corresponding to it one by one ( 1 and then 3) to perform some operations.

Please suggest me an approach.

Comment: `aggregate(1:nrow(df)~TableName, df, toString)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a `dplyr` solution where we create a variable with the `row_number()`, and use that as our index, i.e.

```
df %>% 
 mutate(new = row_number()) %>% 
 group_by(TableName) %>% 
 summarise(Index = toString(new))
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 3 x 2
>   TableName Index
>   <fct>     <chr>
> 1 A         1, 3 
> 2 B         2, 4 
> 3 C         5
> ```

You can also save them as lists rather than strings, which will make future operations easier, i.e.

```
df %>% 
 mutate(new = row_number()) %>% 
 group_by(TableName) %>% 
 summarise(Index = list(new))
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 3 x 2
>   TableName Index    
>   <fct>     <list>   
> 1 A         <int [2]>
> 2 B         <int [2]>
> 3 C         <int [1]>
> ```

Comment: Thanks...This solution came closed to my expectation. Looks like dplyr is indispensable for R.Any good resource or blog for dplyr?

Comment: You can try the [official website](https://www.tidyverse.org/) of the 'verse'. Combine with SO and you 'll be good to go

Comment: hi @Sotos, just one issue i face with the above is that summarise sorts the result by alphabatical order (of TableName), I would not like to sort the data.

Answer (score 2):

Using `data.table`:

```
setDT(data)[, .(Index = toString(.I)), TableName]
   TableName Index
1:         A  1, 3
2:         B  2, 4
3:         C     5
```

Answer (score 2):

No need for any package. Try out:

```
aggregate(rownames(df) ~ TableName, df, c)
  TableName rownames(df)
1         A         1, 3
2         B         2, 4
3         C            5
# or
setNames(aggregate(rownames(df) ~ TableName, df, c),
         c("TableName", "Index"))
  TableName Index
1         A  1, 3
2         B  2, 4
3         C     5
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to use either simply

```
(vec <- tapply(df$Argument, df$TableName, FUN = `identity`))
# $A
# [1] 3 6
#
# $B
# [1] 4 2
#
# $C
# [1] 5
```

or

```
(dfNew <- data.frame(TableName = unique(df$TableName), Index = vec))
#   TableName Index
# A         A  3, 6
# B         B  4, 2
# C         C     5
```

`vec` is a list (rather than a character with concatenated numbers) with easy access to `names(vec)` and, e.g.,

```
vec$A
# [1] 3 6
```

while `dfNew` is a data frame whose second column is also a list:

```
dfNew[2]
#   Index
# A  3, 6
# B  4, 2
# C     5

dfNew[,2]
# [[1]]
# [1] 3 6
#
# [[2]]
# [1] 4 2
#
# [[3]]
# [1] 5

dfNew[2]["A",][[1]]
# [1] 3 6
```

In this case, however, it's not so convenient to reach the indices by `TableName`, so I'd stick with `vec`.